# In derby, how to prepare a statement for updating a column if only knowing the prefix of a column name

Tags: java, sql, derby

if i supposedly have these columns in a table:

GameID, username1, result1, username2, result2, .....

So if i want update a certain userName column at each time, how do I at application level to preprare such dynamic updates statement? (I tried use Update TableName Set like%'username' Where...), but it doesnt like it

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Prepare the right string in your Java code. There's nothing really dynamic here from SQL point of view.

Comment: I just rephrased my question, hope it can be clearer

Comment: Are you using `JDBC` for database access?

Comment: Nope. Not clear. You may want to post your Java code that builds the SQL statement.

Comment: If you have multiple username columns like this, you probably have a mis-/nonunderstanding of how to model data in a relational database. You should perhaps just have {gameid,username,result} and then something like `UPDATE gameresults SET result = 1000 where gameid='doom' and username='Saintor'`

Comment: If you intend to update a singer column and know which one you can construct its name as `"userName" + i`, can't you?

Comment: well the problem is you don't know the i at preparedstatement stage

Comment: You **have** to know `i` by the time you execute your statement.

Comment: Well GameResult table contains a four-persons game wrapped info... do it in your way you need insert 4 times

Comment: No. You can update multiple columns and build your SQL string accordingly.

Comment: Post the actual database schema, and post the actual code you are trying to run, and post the actual error you receive.